# My app crash using OpenAL but only in Release Mode

Tags: c++, openal

I'm building up a complete game engine so, basically, it integrate a sound system. The problem is that a line make me crash in my code. The strange thig is that my app crash ONLY when I compile using Release mode, in Debug Mode it run just fine.

I'm using MSVC 16.XX (I don't know exact version, but it is the latest at the time I am asking this question)

(language used is c++)

```
void PSound::GetDevice()
{
    const ALchar* DeviceList = alcGetString(NULL, ALC_DEVICE_SPECIFIER); //This Line make app crash

    if(DeviceList) {
        while(strlen(DeviceList) > 0) {
            Devices.push_back(DeviceList);
            DeviceList += strlen(DeviceList) + 1;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: What line makes your program crash? Often, "only in release" crashes are related to uninitialized variables, try to run the static analyzer on your code and see if it spots any.

Comment: @Vaillancourt Oh I'm sorry, I edited my post, so now you can see the problematic line

Comment: I'm not able to offer you a fix for this, but does it happen when there are no audio devices enabled? Do you get the device list in debug?

Comment: @Vaillancourt In Debug mode I am totally able to get this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it. It was a very silly problem. There was a project which where not well linked and all the projects were not using the same Runtime Library.